# What can I do with all these crates?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've got roughly a thousand of these useless Mann Co. crates, all of different numbers and seasons and styles, and they are taking up an insane amount of space in my inventory.

What can I do with these crates Valve keeps giving me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Unbox.

   - Unboxing nets you the chance to unbox an Unusual, which far exceeds the cost of unboxing ONE crate
   - You can get cute little hats and miscs to decorate your war veteran with.
   - You can get cute little weapons to arm your war veteran with.
2. Sell on Marketplace

   - Some crates are rarer than others; this means you can sell on the Marketplace for a quick profit.  Most are of low value.
3. Gift to unwilling recipients via "Giftapults"

   - They're only 10cents
   - You can surprise another enemy combatant with this deadly gifting tool
4. Trade with Other Players

   - Some players mass buy crates for unboxing, so having plenty of crates is always a plus
5. Delete

   - Or mass purge, which ever fits your bill

Comment: Also, he can donate them or raffle them off. Check out www.tf2r.com for more info.